# vim: check where a setting value was modified

Tags: vim

I should probably written this down somewhere because it's not easy to remember and not often used. But anyways,

I have a setting like 'expandtab'. I'd like to change to 'noexpandtab'. But I can't figure out in which rc file it was set that takes the last effect. There is a trick to know where a setting was last set. What's the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`:verbose`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:verbose) along with [`:set {option}?`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#E518):

```
:verbose set expandtab?
```

You should see something akin to:

```
  expandtab                                                                                                                                                                                                
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
```